# How to fix ReferenceError: _gaq is not defined

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I am trying to implement google-analytics-goals-button-tracking in my page but
got error '_gaq is not defined', how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are trying to use ga.js and the old _gaq push queue, which is a really old library. Have you added analytics.js to your website and then perhaps using old documentation which is for ga.js?

From Google dev:
[ga.js is a legacy library.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gaq) If you are starting a new implementation, we recommend you use the latest version of this library, analytics.js. For existing implementations, learn how to migrate from ga.js to analytics.js.